# Trying to redirect page after login validation using javascript and html, won't work

Tags: javascript, html

So just starting coding in html and js, need some help as to why the page isn't redirecting after validation. The page just resets after logging in, and i'm trying to get it to redirect to login.html. Any help please?

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Task Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src ="login.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>Task Manager</h1>
      <form method="post">
        <div  class="txt_field">
          <input type="text" required name="" id="username">
          <span></span>
          <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="txt_field">
          <input type="password" name=""  id="password">
          <span></span>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="pass">Forgot Password?</div>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login"  onclick="validate()">
        <div class="signup_link">
          Not a member? <a href="#">Signup</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function validate()
{
var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
if(username=="admin"&& password=="user")

{

    alert("login succesfully");
    window.location.href = "./todo.html";

    return false;
    
}
else
{
    alert("login failed");
    return false;


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the java script in the return part so I don't remember exactly how to end the redirect in true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can change
`window.location.href = "./todo.html";`
to
`window.location = "./todo.html";`

Comment: this didn't solve the issue

Comment: in your question you state you're trying to redirect to login.html, but in your javascript you set the window location to todo.html, is this intentional?